# How to find a fix number of (almost) fixed proportion rectangles with opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I am writing a simple fly tracking software and I would love some input from opencv experts.

The image I have looks pretty much like:

[image: sample image for fly tracking]

I used to do tracking using kmeans and PIL/numpy but I re-wrote everything to use blob detection in opencv. Tracking works OK but I would also like to automatize division of ROI. 
What I need to do is find each of the 32 grooves that appear in the picture, where flies live. See the black rectangle on the image as example of what I mean.

I think cornerHarris may be what I need but how do I specify only the grooves and not each single rectangle found in the image? All those grooves have proportions of roughly 10:1.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your camera and fly apparatus stationary? If so, then finding the rectangles might be a good candidate to do manually. It would take a human only a few minutes to draw the rectangles on, and if everything is stationary, then you would never need to draw them again.

Comment: @AndyL, yes it is quite stationary once the experiment starts but it may vary slightly from experiment to experiment. In the past it was working exactly as you suggested but now that I moved everything to opencv I am trying to gain the most out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think *cvCornerHarris* is even close to what you need.

A much better start would be to experiment with the demo available at: `OpenCV-2.3.0/samples/cpp/squares.cpp`. This technique uses `Canny()`, `dilate()` and `findCountour()`.

Right out of the box, this demo outputs:

[image]

I believe that with a few tweaks here and there you can have your party started.

Comment: I know it's not python, but I trust you can port a C++ code of OpenCV to it's python equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! I found the phyton port [here](http://haidersabri.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/squares.py). Is a bit buggy (the threshold bar is actually not working) but [I fixed it](http://pastebin.com/bcgK0TN2) and I get exactly the same output you show. Filtering out rects by size and proportion I get no false positive but a lot of false negatives: I can correctly mark no more than 6 or so.

Comment: or maybe consider only the horizontal lines in a probabilistic Hough line transform? just saying.

Comment: @AruniRC I've played a bit with Hough lines on this image before posting my answer. I couldn't find a better result than the one above. It doesn't mean that it can't be done, though. You're welcome to try.

Comment: I think I am going to do the following: using a permanent marker paint the upper side of the walls between one groove and the other in RED. Acquire the image, split the channels and find the squares only in the red channel. That should work.

Comment: If you know the number of small groves and their aspect ratios, you could simply identify the corners of the larger window that encompasses the small groves, and then use vector algebra to work out the coordinates of the sub rectangles that make up the grooves. This makes your problem much easier, because you are only using image processing to find ONE rectangle, and you are inferring the location of  the others from that.

Comment: In that case this code can still be used. Just look for the 2nd biggest rectangle found in the image. That would be the corner of the white device(?) you are working with.

Comment: @crocowhile: Sounds like we are both using OpenCV and image processing to study model organisms. Shoot me an email if you would like to discuss more.